# CS-Cart category image in menu

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

In CS-Cart on a categories page you get a list of subcategories with images if one has been uploaded.

How can I get the category image to also show in the main menu (topmenu_dropdown.tpl)?

I have tried using something like:

```
{include file="common/image.tpl" images=$item2.main_pair image_width=150}
```

but it looks like the image is not being made available to topmenu_dropdown.tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this so will post for others that may need it.

This is possible using the very useful `fn_get_category_data` which enables you to get data from a category.

In the `topmenu_dropdown.tpl` you first need to find the category ID. While this is not directly available, you can get it off the end of the `href` variable. (This is only possible if it is an auto generated category menu)

```
{assign var=catid value="="|explode:$item2.href}
```

This will make an array by splitting href at the = sign.

```
{$category_data = $catid.1|fn_get_category_data}
```

Then you can use the id number to get the correct category data.

Now `$category_data` will have all the variables you want including the desired image using `$category_data.main_pair`

Answer (score 0):

In last, I got a new idea to show the category image in the menu.

And More thankful for getting the category id from

> $item2 object

as shown in [CS-Cart category image in menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705114/cs-cart-category-image-in-menu/49941443#49941443)

```
{assign var=catid value="="|explode:$item2.href}
{assign var="cat_image" value=$catid.1|fn_get_image_pairs:'category':'M':true:true}
{if $cat_image.pair_id}
    <div class="categories-image">
        {include file="common/image.tpl" images=$cat_image.detailed image_width=150}
    </div>
{/if}
```